# Omission of a sunnah act of the prayer in the maliki mazhab

Tags: salat, sunnah, maliki

Is it true that in the Maliki mazhab omission of the sunnah acts of the prayer requires a prostation of forgetfulness otherwise the prayer wont be valid is this true?

Comment: This should be the case for any other madhhab too as omission of a fard act means your prayer is invalid. I rather guess it is a question of definition of terms.

Comment: I didnt say fard act

Comment: Yes because omission of sunnah requires prostration of forgetfulness in any madhhab as I said.